# Como utilizar dialogs em GTK+

Tags: c, gtk

Estive procurando na internet como utilizar `dialogs` em GTK+, e acabei achando um punhado de artigos em inglês e nenhum em português. Lendo os artigos em inglêS, visto que possuo entendimento com este idioma, não consegui descobrir a coerência que o autor queria transmitir, sendo assim, não sei como utilizar dialogs em GTK+.

Poderiam me explicar?

Comment: Só uma duvida, o seu problema são os widgets (janelas, dialogs) ou você não esta conseguindo compilar nada, nem mesmo uma tela de prompt?

Comment: Assim, o básico do GTK+ eu sei. Posso dizer que sou faixa amarela, rs.
O problema é que não consigo compreender os dialogs, queria tipo uma aula, entende? A única coisa que sei sobre eles é que são janelas popup

Comment: GtkDialog é apenas uma GtkWindow com alguns widgets pré-definidos. Na prática é apenas um componente de "conveniência" para facilitar a padronização da interface e dar menos trabalho ao programador.

Comment: Certo. Mas se quer melhor resposta, me dê uma "aula" sobre os dialogs.

Comment: Como assim "não está clara o suficiente"? Eu até compreenderia a pergunta ser marcada como ampla demais para quem acha que não dá pra falar tudo sobre GtkDialog numa resposta, mas está bastante clara pra mim: o cara quer saber como usar GtkDialog. Se vocês fizerem uma rápida busca por "como utilizar" ou "como usar" vão encontrar um monte de perguntas abertas no mesmo espírito.